# Glassfish v3 Mac

Tags: macos, glassfish

I have trouble launching Glassfish v3 on Mac

In Windows, after installation of Glassfish v3 Shortcuts for Starting and Stopping server are added to Start Menu

In Mac how do I start the server? I tried executing ./asadmin start-domain domain1
but it gives me an error for missing .xml files

Any sort of help is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention how you installed, but it sounds like the install didn't complete correctly.

I start Glassfish on my Mac every day with

```
./asadmin start-domain
```

in the bin directory of the install home.  Note that if you don't specify the domain, it uses domain1 as the default.

Try using the Unix installer, it's a self-extracting shell program - b69 is the latest for v3.  After a complete install, it should work fine.  The usual caveats (make sure you have enough diskspace, etc) apply.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with it so I installed Eclipse and let it install Glassfish for me. Everything works fine now.

One thing I don't really understand is that in order to create a new JPA project without errors. You need to install glassfish in the same folder that you save your project files on Mac. But, this doesn't seems to be the case for Windows.